# Matlab fast summation

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I was wondering whether there is a faster way to evaluate this double sum in matlab:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\text{max}} \sum_{m=-n}^{n} f(n,m).$$
Cause I am currently doing this with a foor loop over n and m and noticed that my code is tremendously slow. ( I know that matlab is faster with vectorized code, but I do not really know what actually the best alternative is)

Comment: Use the loop to figure only the input args, which will create a 2xN array, where N is the total number of combinations. Then just use `sum(f(x))`, where `x` is the previously mentioned 2xN array.

Comment: Tell us what $f(n,m)$ is. It might have some symmetries so the sum can be done in better way. I have in mind something like FFT.

Comment: sorry, this was more or less a general question and  $f(n,m)$ is different every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to generate a static $2\times N$ array with
$$N = \sum_{n=1}^{\text{max}_n} 2n + 1 = \text{max}_n + \text{max}_n(\text{max}_n + 1) = \text{max}_n^2 + 2\text{max}_n$$
Note $(n-1)^2 + 2(n-1) = n^2 - 1$

`MN = zeros(2,maxn^2 + 2*maxn);

for n=1:maxn

tmp = n*ones(2,2*n + 1);

tmp(2,:) = -n:n;

R = (0:2*n) + n^2;

MN(:,R) = tmp;

end`

<strike>*not tested*, as I have no access to MATLAB right now.</strike>

Then, using save / load you use
`sum(f(MN))`
for the summation.

**EDIT**: The line with `R = ...` was bugged. I've fixed it; this way it seems to work. Note, that $f$ must take a $2\times1$ (column)-Vector as input per point.

Comment: Did you test this in MATLAB? Did it work? Does it need any modifications / contain any bugs?

Comment: I will not be able to test it today, but I will leave a comment.

Comment: @Lipschitz Alright, thanks.